# automate changing configuration on 192.168.0.x

Tags: security, automation, localhost

I have a few motion detection cameras setup in an office. I'm able to manually log into 192.168.0.X, 192.168.0.Y, 192.168.0.Z, so forth and in each dashboard turn motion detection on and off.  However, I'm looking for a way to automate this and be able to hit an internal address on my network that will do these actions for me.  Also, I'd like to be able to hit this same internal address from my phone when I'm on my network to arm and disarm the cameras.

What is the best way to handle creating an internal address that I can only see on my network and automate submitting a form from a script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"an internal address" means you need to be running a Web server. A simple Linux box with LAMP will do the trick. Then, write a PHP script that uses CURL to automate the Web requests to the cameras.